# splitting a string in python having multiple splitters

Tags: python

How to split a string variable like below into individual groups? `var.split(",")` splits those inside the brackets also.

```
var = "(5, 'kghjsg'), (6, 'kghjsghk'), (7, 'jksgjsg'), (8, 'ksgshgk'), (9, 'hjsdhg')"
```

desired result:

```
[(5, 'kghjsg'),  
(6, 'kghjsghk'), 
..
]
```

Comment: Is your string guaranteed to be in that format? If so, you can use `literal_eval()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> var = "(5, 'kghjsg'), (6, 'kghjsghk'), (7, 'jksgjsg'), (8, 'ksgshgk'), (9, 'hjsdhg')"
>>> literal_eval(var)
((5, 'kghjsg'), (6, 'kghjsghk'), (7, 'jksgjsg'), (8, 'ksgshgk'), (9, 'hjsdhg'))
```

From docs:

> Safely evaluate an expression node or a Unicode or Latin-1 encoded
>   string containing a **Python expression**. The string or node provided may
>   only consist of the following Python literal structures: `strings`,
>   `numbers`, `tuples`, `lists`, `dicts`, `booleans`, and `None`.

Comment: Note this assumes the string to be parsed is a valid Python expression.